# How to write shell script to find and exclude files from text file

Tags: shell

I'm finding it difficult to come up with a shell script to read a txt file and exclude the those files mentioned in the text file while zipping .
Any inputs ?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following folder

```
$> ls test
a b c
```

and the following ignore list

```
$> cat ignore_list
test/b
```

You can use the -x option combined with a list to exclude some files:

```
zip -r archive test/ -x@ignore_list
```

output:

```
adding: test/ (stored 0%)
adding: test/c (stored 0%)
adding: test/a (stored 0%)
```

Example from the man page:

```
zip -r foo foo -x@exclude.lst
```